# How to supply arguments for GLES20.glClearColor() from colors.xml?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In application's *res/values/colors.xml* file, a red color is defined in *#AARRGGBB* format:

```
    <color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

How to use this color as an argument to glClearColor and other OpenGL ES functions?
For example:

```
     public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
         GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // <-- How to connect R.color.red here? 
     }
```

Comment: I think you can get the number you defined (as an int), with something like `getResources().getColor(R.color.red)`. Used for stuff like `setBackgroundColor`. But you want to convert this to a float array of arguments, right?

Comment: @Kᴇʏsᴇʀ Exactly. Using getResources().getColor(R.color.red) in other places of the application. Can't connect to OpenGL ES in a natural way.

Comment: Not sure if you can define float arrays in xml. You can define string or int arrays though. I have no idea how people generally do it. Perhaps using a static class instead of xml? Another option is to write some converter method that takes the int and returns a float array. You might want to browse some source code.

Comment: All the code I inspected, defines colors right in the function calls, like this GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f).

Comment: In that case, the only suggestion I have is to make a class filled with color constants (arrays in this case). Though you won't get nice looking method calls without a wrapper (which might be bad practice, not sure :p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use shifts to isolate the individual bytes, cast them to floats and then divide to scale them down to the range 0.0f to 1.0f.  It should look like this:

```
   unsigned long uColor; // #AARRGGBB format

    float fAlpha = (float)(uColor >> 24) / 0xFF
    float fRed = (float)((uColor >> 16) & 0xFF) / 0xFF;
    float fGreen = (float)((uColor >> 8) & 0xFF) / 0xFF;
    float fBlue = (float)(uColor & 0xFF) / 0xFF;

    GLES20.glClearColor(fRed, fGreen, fBlue, fAlpha);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Color` class has static methods to support this. If `strColor` is a color in string format, which can be `#RRGGBB`, `#AARRGGBB`, or the name of a color, you can use the following to convert it to the values you need for OpenGL:

```
int intColor = Color.parseColor(strColor);
GLES20.glClearColor(Color.red(intColor) / 255.0f,
                    Color.green(intColor) / 255.0f,
                    Color.blue(intColor) / 255.0f);
```

Comment: This is the better answer.  Although it's best that you perform this calculation upon creation of the instance and then reference the RGB values in your `onSurfaceCreated` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to convert a color from HEX to glClearColor() format which is a float between 0 and 1.

First I convert the color to RGB, then I map that color from 0 to 1.

```
/* re-map RGB colors so they can be used in OpenGL */
private float[] map(float[]rgb) {

    /* RGB is from 0 to 255 */
    /* THIS is from 0 to 1 (float) */

    // 1 : 2 = x : 4 >>> 2

    /*
    *
    * 240 : 255 = x : 1
    *
    * */

    float[] result = new float[3];
    result[0] = rgb[0] / 255;
    result[1] = rgb[1] / 255;
    result[2] = rgb[2] / 255;
    return result;
}

public float[] hextoRGB(String hex) {

    float[] rgbcolor = new float[3];
    rgbcolor[0] = Integer.valueOf( hex.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 );
    rgbcolor[1] = Integer.valueOf( hex.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 );
    rgbcolor[2] = Integer.valueOf( hex.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 );
    return map(rgbcolor);
}
```

Usage:

```
    //0077AB is HEX color code
    float[] values = hextoRGB("#0077AB");

    GLES20.glClearColor(values[0], values[1], values[2], 1.0f);
```